# Коварный global

Tags: python, tkinter

подскажите пожалуйста почему в функции fileOpen() не удаётся вывести WorkArea, не сделав предварительно объявление
global WorkArea
(выводится какая-то цифра, но не в этом суть)

```
import tkinter

def fileNew(parent):
    global WorkArea
    WorkArea = tkinter.Text(parent)
    WorkArea.pack(expand = 'yes', fill = 'both')

def fileOpen():
    global WorkArea
    print(WorkArea)
    openFile = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(title = 'Open textPad file', filetypes=[("textPad files", "*.tpd")])
    file = open(openFile, 'rt')

    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        WorkArea.insert(tkinter.END, line)

    file.close()

def fileSave():
    text = WorkArea.get('0.0', tkinter.END)
    print(text)
    save = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title = 'Save textPad file', filetypes=[("textPad files", "*.tpd")], defaultextension = '.tpd')
    file = open(save, 'wt')
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

def fileClose():
    WorkArea.destroy()

def makeMenu(parent):
    top = tkinter.Menu(parent) 
    parent.config(menu = top)

    file = tkinter.Menu(top, tearoff = False)
    file.add_command(label = 'New...', command = lambda: fileNew(parent))
    file.add_command(label = 'Open...', command = fileOpen)
    file.add_command(label = 'Save...', command = fileSave)
    file.add_command(label = 'Close...', command = fileClose)
    file.add_command(label = 'Quit', command = parent.quit)
    top.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = file)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1000x500")

makeMenu(root)

root.mainloop()
```

в функции fileSave() тоже используется WorkArea, но там её не требуется объявлять как global. мне это не понятно

инструкцию global я понимаю следующим образом. какая-либо функция(например fileNew()) присваивает значение переменной. а потом посредством global выталкивает её в глобальную область видимости. далее другая функция(например fileClose() ищет переменную в своей области видимости, но не находит). после этого ищет переменную во внешней области видимости и находит её там(так как переменная ранее вытолкнута в глобальную область функцией fileNew()).
однако fileOpen() не может подобным образом найти переменную в глобальной области видимости без объявления global WorkArea. это непонятно

Comment: @Sergey Kalinin читаем, что написано про global:

    The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global. 

Выталкивание в данном случае термин неправильный. Что касается fileOpen(), то она при отсутствующей WorkArea и не работает, несмотря на присутствие global. Если Вы создали переменную в fileNew() -- тогда и global в fileOpen необязателен.

Comment: Путь в ад программирования вымощен глобальными переменными. Немного оффтоп, но глобальных переменных стоит вообще избегать, а отсутствие оных -- признак хорошего дизайна программы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы не используете глобальную переменную.
Вы её замещаете в строке:

```
WorkArea = tkinter.Text(parent)
```

Comment: @prospero78su, global WorkArea как раз таки и говорит, что в функции используется глобальная переменная WorkArea.

Answer (score 0):

```
# и что тут не работает?

def fileNew():
    global WorkArea
    WorkArea = {'0.0': True}

def fileOpen():
    print(WorkArea)  # {'0.0': True}

def fileSave():
    text = WorkArea.get('0.0', False)
    print(text)  # True

fileNew()
fileOpen()
fileSave()
```